# Apache 2.2 IP address blacklist

Tags: apache-2.2, blacklist, rewritemap

I wanted to blacklist on the fly some IP address. I'm updating the main httpd.conf but i wanted to add some IPs on the fly, without using .htaccess (neither the heavy fail2ban).
So, i creating a list of ip using Rewrite map. It's working well, except if i want to output the 403 error.

Here is the code that is working :

```
<VirtualHost x.x.x.x:80>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteMap hosts-deny "txt:/var/www/htdocs/.deny"
RewriteCond   "${hosts-deny:%{REMOTE_ADDR}|NOT-FOUND}" ^-$ [NC] 
RewriteRule   .* /var/www/htdocs/error.php [L]
```

but It would make more sense for me to have it that way, meaning generating the 403 error :

```
<VirtualHost x.x.x.x:80>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteMap hosts-deny "txt:/var/www/htdocs/.deny"
RewriteCond   "${hosts-deny:%{REMOTE_ADDR}|NOT-FOUND}" ^-$ [NC] 
RewriteRule   .* - [L,F]
```

but then it thought out the following error
"You don't have permission to access /index.php on this server." 
Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

but there is already a 403 error page that is working (located there /var/www/htdocs/error.php),
i've tried to move the definition outside the  section where it is working for the rest of the site, except for this new set up

```
ErrorDocument 403 /error.php
```

or

```
ErrorDocument 403 /var/www/htdocs/error.php
```

none are working, meaning, i still have the 500 internal server error

Any idea where i am wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the `ErrorDocument` must be available for the client. You have to insert a special rule allowing the download of that one file in order not to get an internal error. Something like this should do:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteMap hosts-deny "txt:/var/www/htdocs/.deny"
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_URI} !^/error.php$
RewriteCond   "${hosts-deny:%{REMOTE_ADDR}|NOT-FOUND}" ^-$ [NC] 
RewriteRule   .* - [L,F]
```

This also means that the first `ErrorDocument` directive is right: since the document gets served from the virtual host, it must be relative to the webroot (i.e. it should be `/error.php`, not `/var/www/htdocs/error.php`).